# Windows SSH ProxyCommand /usr/bin/bash: line 0: exec: nc: not found on git bash

Tags: windows, ssh, proxy, netcat, jumphost

I am trying to SSH to a server via an intermediately jump host on Windows Git Bash but I get the following error.

**/usr/bin/bash: line 0: exec: nc: not found**

```
$ ssh -vnNT -L 2555:destination-server.com ubuntu@x.amazonaws.com -o "ProxyCommand=nc -X 5 -x proxy.abc.com:4850 %h %p"

OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec nc -X 5 -x proxy.abc.com:4850 x.amazonaws.com 22
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8
/usr/bin/bash: line 0: exec: nc: not found *********************************** => ERROR LINE
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 6):

#### The reason is that Git Bash for Windows has no `nc (netcat)` command.

##### As a workaround please replace:

```
nc -X 5 -x proxy.abc.com:4850 %h %p
```

##### with

```
connect -S proxy.abc.com:4850 %h %p
```

So the final command would be:

```
ssh -vnNT -L 2555:destination-server.com ubuntu@x.amazonaws.com -o "ProxyCommand=connect -S proxy.abc.com:4850 %h %p"
```

Even if you're using `nc` from an ssh config file, you can replace `nc -X 5 -x` with `connect -S`, and it should work.

Example:

Replace

[image: Replace]

with

[image: working command]

Comment: Hi, where can I find the `connect` command? It looks like when I type the `whereis connect` under the git for windows bash shell, it returns nothing. Thanks.